# catkin_make error when build talker and listener

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the tutorials and make talker.cpp and listener.cpp in the dir ~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src. I add the CMakelist.txt like the following lines:

```
add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

but when I cd ~/catkin_ws and catkin_make this error happened :

```
Base path: /home/linux/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/linux/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/linux/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/linux/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/linux/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/linux/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j2 -l2" in "/home/linux/catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target listener
Scanning dependencies of target talker
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/build'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:473: recipe for target 'beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 50%] Building CXX object beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/talker.dir/src/talker.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/linux/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/talker
[100%] Built target talker
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

So what should I do to solve the problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260163/catkin_make-error-when-build-talker-and-listener/) by [Caryzhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30143/caryzhou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check that `listener.cpp` is in the specified directory and has the correct name.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.ros.org/users/20033/nlamprian/) with karma: 366 on 2017-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Caryzhou](https://answers.ros.org/users/30143/caryzhou/) on 2017-04-25**:
thank you I'sorry to  name the file the wrong name ,thank you very much!